# Cannot add new Given/When/Then, getting error `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /`

Tags: javascript, protractor, gherkin, cucumberjs

I had configured cucumber + protractor, and I firstly was splitting stepDefinitions into different files like this:

[image: stepdefinitions]

When I created new features files, and started running, cucumber/protractor did not recognized these new steps I was adding to the other files. So I decided to move all the new steps into the same file.

But when I run, although they are well written (checked and compared thousands of times)  I getting this error:

```
    [launcher] Error: /Users/brunosoko/Documents/Dev/Personal/test2/features/step_definitions/homepage/homepage.js:30
    this.When(/^I select an image      or video$/, function (done) {
              ^
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at /Users/brunosoko/Documents/Dev/Personal/test2/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cucumber/cli/support_code_loader.js:63:29
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.wrapper (/Users/brunosoko/Documents/Dev/Personal/olapic-test2/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cucumber/cli/support_code_loader.js:62:15)
```

I've the following versions running of protractor and cucumber:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "*",
    "chai-as-promised": "^5.1.0",
    "cucumber": "~0.6.0",
    "protractor": "1.4.0",
    "protractor-cucumber-junit": "latest",
    "protractor-html-screenshot-reporter": "^0.0.21",
    "selenium-webdriver": "2.47.0"   },
```

These are my stepDefinition:

````
```
    /*Given*/
    this.Given(/^I am at the homepage$/, function (done) {
        browser.get('').then(function(){
            CarouselPage.clickOutSidePopUp();
            done();
        });
    });
    this.Given(/^I can see that images and videos are present on the widget$/      , function (done) {
        expect(CarouselPage.checkMediaSource()).to.eventually.be.true;
        done();
    });


    this.When(/^I select an image      or video$/, function (done) {
        CarouselPage.getMedia(1).click();
        done();
    });


    /*Then*/
    this.Then(/^I see that Carousel Widget is correctly displayed$/, function(done){
        expect(CarouselPage.carouselContainer.isPresent()).to.eventually.be.true;
        done();
    });

    this.Then(/^I see the viewer modal               $/, function(done){
        expect(ViewerModal.viewerContainer.isPresent()).to.eventually.be.true;
        done();
    });

    this.Then(/^I see the Gallery widget     $/, function(done){
        expect(CarouselPage.carouselContainer.isPresent()).to.eventually.be.true;
        done();
    }); ```
````

So, what am I doing wrong? Do I need to clear some cache? is this a bug with the versions I am using?

Thanks!

*NOTE:*
What also called my attention is that if I even comment the whole step, I see this on the console

```
./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor conf.js
util.puts: Use console.log instead
Starting selenium standalone server...
util.puts: Use console.log instead
Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.0.101:58696/wd/hub
[launcher] Error: /Users/brunosoko/Documents/Dev/Personal/test2/features/step_definitions/homepage/stepsDefinitions.js:24
    //this.When(/^I select an image      or video$/, function (done) {
                                        ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at /Users/brunosoko/Documents/Dev/Personal/test2/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cucumber/cli/support_code_loader.js:63:29
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.wrapper (/Users/brunosoko/Documents/Dev/Personal/test2/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cucumber/cli/support_code_loader.js:62:15)
```

*EDIT 2:*
Here's my `conf.js` file, in case you see I'm doing wrong something here as well

```
exports.config = {
    specs: [
        'features/*.feature'
    ],
    baseUrl: "http://www.page.com",
    multiCapabilities: [
        {
            'browserName': 'chrome'
        }
    ],
    framework: 'cucumber',
    //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    cucumberOpts: {
        require: 'features/step_definitions/**/*.js',
        format: 'pretty'
    },
    resultJsonOutputFile: 'report.json',

    onPrepare: function () {

        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

        browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20000);

        browser.getCapabilities().then(function (cap) {
            browserName = cap.caps_.browserName;
        });

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first character after `image` is a [unicode line separator](http://unicode-table.com/en/2028/). Delete that and node will be able to parse the regular expression.

Comment: On my text editor that unicode line was not shown! solved the issue! thanks!